# Adding content block within Rails link_to tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `link_to` Rails tag in the following form:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', somePath, 
method: :delete, confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this?", 
class: "delete" %>
```

I've been trying to add a `do` block to add some arbitrary content block within the generated anchor tag. I've tried the following, but to no avail:

```
<%= link_to '<content>Delete' ... %>
# Which yields => <content>Delete in the DOM as a string instead of HTML
```

and

```
<%= link_to 'Delete' ... class: "delete" do %>
    <content>
<% end %>
```

Which throws the error `undefined method 'stringify_keys'`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
<%= link_to url_path ... class: "delete" do %>
  Delete <content>
<% end %>
```